# how to reorder css-elements without js

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### Problem

I have a 2-column-layout where the left column contains the elements 1 and 5 and the right column contains 2, 3 and 4.

On mobile screens I want to have a single column only where the order is 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5:

```
Desktop               Mobile

┌───────┬───────┐     ┌───────┐
│     1 │     2 │     │     1 │
├───────┼───────┤     ├───────┤
│     5 │     3 │     │     2 │
│       ├───────┤     ├───────┤
└───────┤     4 │     │     3 │
        └───────┘     ├───────┤
                      │     4 │
                      ├───────┤
                      │     5 │
                      │       │
                      └───────┘
```

Some requirements:

- I don't know the height of the boxes in advance
- It could be that all boxes have different heights
- I don't want to alter their height
- Either the left, or right side could be higher

I know I can reorder elements with flex. I also know that I can create cols and rows with flex, however all elements have dynamic heights. Is there any way to achieve this effect without using js?

### Example Code

#### demo without flex

The problem here is that the order is not correct on mobile screens.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.container .left, .container .right {
  width: 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container .left, .container .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.container .box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .box.a {
  height: 80px;
}
.container .box.b {
  height: 150px;
}
.container .box.d {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box a"><span>1 - static height</span></div>
    <div class="box b"><span>5 - dynamic height</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box c"><span>2 - dynamic height</span></div>
    <div class="box d"><span>3 - dynamic height</span></div>
    <div class="box e"><span>4 - dynamic height</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### demo with flex

The problem here is that the container needs to have a *correct* height, but since each boxes height is determined by its contents, I can not know the *correct* height.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    /* This is assumed for demonstration-purposes.
    // I don't know that height in advance. I just set
    // it to smth. so that exactly 1 and 5 are fitting
    // into the left col */
    height: 170px;
  }
  
  .box {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .b {
    order: -1;
  }
  
  .a {
    order: -2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box a"><span>1 - static height</span></div>
    <div class="box c"><span>2 - dynamic height</span></div>
    <div class="box d"><span>3 - dynamic height</span></div>
    <div class="box e"><span>4 - dynamic height</span></div>
    <div class="box b"><span>5 - dynamic height<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your flex solution? That the height of the container should stay 170px?

Comment: I can not give the container a height because I don't know the height of the boxes in advance. The height of each box is determined by its contents. Calculating the height via js is very faulty in cases of zooming / responsive styles / contents that change their height after being rendered (like accordeons)

Comment: What are you looking for? both columns to be the same height?

Comment: Nope, the height should be dynamic. I just want to preserve the order as drawn in the ascii-art and which box is in which col. i.e: I want the left col to always contain 1 and 5, no matter how high or narrow each box is

Comment: To make sure I understand: On desktops, you *always* want boxes 1 and 5 in a column on the left, and boxes 2, 3, and 4 in a column on the right. But on mobile, you *always* want all 5 boxes stacked in an ordered column, 1-5, no matter the heights of any of them?

Comment: @freginold exactly as you say!

Comment: Will it always be the same 5 boxes (albeit with different sizes?)

Comment: @freignold - yes. There are always five boxes with distinctive classes in always the same order

Comment: Basically you can't do that with flexbox...without `display:contents` which isn't properly supported as yet. On the other hand CSS Grid can do that with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```css
html{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
*,
:after,
:before{
  box-sizing:inherit;
}

.box {
  border: solid 1px pink;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.a {
  order: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  order: 1;
}
.e {
  order: 2;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
  .a,
  .e {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
  }

  .b,
  .c,
  .d {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box b"><span>2 - dynamic height</span></div>
    <div class="box c"><span>3 - dynamic height</span></div>
    <div class="box d"><span>4 - dynamic height</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box a"><span>1 - static height</span></div>
  <div class="box e"><span>5 - dynamic height<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo</span></div>
</div>
```